# Form data not being passed through, coming back with 301 permanently moved error (using laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

For whatever reason, this is returning a 301 Permanently Moved error in my Inspector/Network window. It is not posting the form data to the table either.

index.blade.php file

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/')) }}
{{ Form::text('firstname' , '', array('placeholder' => 'first name'))}}
{{ Form::text('lastname' , '', array('placeholder' => 'last name'))}}
{{ Form::submit('add name', array('class' => 'btn btn-success'))}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Route file

```
 <?php

 Route::get('/', function(){
return View::make('index');
  });

  Route::post('/', function() {

$input = Input::all();

DB::insert('insert into Donkey (firstname, lastname) values (?, ?)', array($input['firstname'], $input['lastname']));
  });
```

any ideas?

Comment: Try adding return to that closure

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, use following instead:

```
$input = Input::all();
DB::table('Donkey')->insert(
    array('firstname' => $input['firstname'], 'lastname' => $input['lastname'])
);
```

Comment: OP's code should work either as it's Connection insert() method and it seems the problem is not with the query but routing.